# How to exchange the width and height of W35 Touchscreen for Mini2440 FriendlyARM embedded board

Tags: qt, arm

I have a Friendly-ARM embedded board with a W35 3.5" Touchscreen. You can see the board via the following link: http://www.friendlyarm.net/sites/products/mini2440-35s.jpg. Also I write QT program for that using Qt Creator. I have to write a GUI using QT with Width x Height = 240 x 320. I mean width = 240 and height = 320. According to what I found at various online documents and pages, the dimensions of W35 are 320 x 240, it means width = 320 and height = 320. So when I run the program, there are large margins at left and right and some part of GUI is cut at top and button. How do I exchange the board width and height?

The closest page I found on Friendly-ARM site is: http://www.friendlyarm.net/forum/topic/2881.
At this page someone mentioned, there is a file s3c2410.c at drivers/video directory, or there is file mach-mini2440.c at arch/arm/mach-s3c2440 directory and we should tweak some C #define, but I don't have neither one on the board kernel. What should I do?

1) Reinstalling the Kernel?

2) Writing program for 320 x 240 instead of 240 x 320

3) Changing the touchscreen to similar ones like X35 or T35

FYI, when the board starts up, there is Qtopia with right dimensions.

TIA,

-- Saeed Amrollahi Boyouki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all cross-compile your Qt with `-qt-gfx-transformed` option.

Method 1:
You can rotate your Qt Application using

```
./myApp -qws -display ":Transformed:Rot90:0"
```

Method 2:
You can set Display Dimension using

```
export QWS_DISPLAY=Transformed:Rot90:0
```

and start your application using

```
./myApp -qws
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to look for are instructions to rotate the display from "landscape" mode to "portrait" mode.  I am unsure if there is a hardware option on the ARM processor included in the FriendlyArm, but that gives you a place to start searching.  I'd also look in the Qtopia forums for a similar switch, ie http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/8875 or similar.